# Is there a way to improve starlark's unittest error reporting?

Tags: bazel, starlark

I'm writing analysis-time tests for my project as per https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/testing.html and I'm wondering what the most useful way of reporting failures is.

Using the `unittest.bzl` module, I am using `asserts.equals`, `asserts.true` etc and find the error reporting in the logs somewhat lacking. For example, if an `asserts.true` fails the error message is `Expected condition to be true, but was false`, with no mention of which line, or what the condition it expected to be true was. In a file full of lots of tests, this isn't very useful! I'm aware one can add a message as an argument to these assertions, but having tailored messages for every assertion doesn't feel ideal either. Is there a way to get at the backtrace caused by the assertion failure at all? Or any other way of accessing the line number/details of assertion failure?

Answer (score 0):

I took the [minimal example](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/testing.html#minimal-example) from your link and added the [latest](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-skylib/releases/tag/1.0.3) Skylib release to a new WORKSPACE. I then changed the expected value in `_provider_contents_test_impl` to make the test fail.

Below is the full output, note the `DEBUG` that contains a lot of useful info (file, line, expectation, actual value).

```
$ bazel test //mypkg:myrules_test                                             
DEBUG: /home/user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_user/863abec759a50d843603ddf033727331/external/bazel_skylib/lib/unittest.bzl:351:10: In test _provider_contents_test_impl from //mypkg:myrules_test.bzl: Expected "some valuexxxxx", but got "some value"
INFO: Analyzed target //mypkg:provider_contents_test (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 test target...
FAIL: //mypkg:provider_contents_test (see /home/user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_user/863abec759a50d843603ddf033727331/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/testlogs/mypkg/provider_contents_test/test.log)
Target //mypkg:provider_contents_test up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/mypkg/provider_contents_test.sh
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.108s, Critical Path: 0.04s
INFO: 2 processes: 2 linux-sandbox.
INFO: Build completed, 1 test FAILED, 2 total actions
//mypkg:provider_contents_test                                           FAILED in 0.0s
  /home/user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_user/863abec759a50d843603ddf033727331/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/testlogs/mypkg/provider_contents_test/test.log

INFO: Build completed, 1 test FAILED, 2 total actions
```

Tracebacks are also supported, see [this bug report](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-skylib/issues/255) for example.

tion, actual value).

```
$ bazel test //mypkg:myrules_test                                             
DEBUG: /home/user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_user/863abec759a50d843603ddf033727331/external/bazel_skylib/lib/unittest.bzl:351:10: In test _provider_contents_test_impl from //mypkg:myrules_test.bzl: Expected "some valuexxxxx", but got "some value"
INFO: Analyzed target //mypkg:provider_contents_test (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 test target...
FAIL: //mypkg:provider_contents_test (see /home/user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_user/863abec759a50d843603ddf033727331/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/testlogs/mypkg/provider_contents_test/test.log)
Target //mypkg:provider_contents_test up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/mypkg/provider_contents_test.sh
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.108s, Critical Path: 0.04s
INFO: 2 processes: 2 linux-sandbox.
INFO: Build completed, 1 test FAILED, 2 total actions
//mypkg:provider_contents_test                                           FAILED in 0.0s
  /home/user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_user/863abec759a50d843603ddf033727331/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/testlogs/mypkg/provider_contents_test/test.log

INFO: Build completed, 1 test FAILED, 2 total actions
```

Tracebacks are also supported, see [this bug report](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-skylib/issues/255) for example.

Note that `asserts.equals` will print the actual value on failure, but `asserts.true` will not - but you can easily work around this by using `asserts.equals(env, True, test_val, msg)` instead.